# What is the source range of the GCE L7?

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-health-check

In the [K8s documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/gce/BETA_LIMITATIONS.md#creating-the-firewall-rule-for-glbc-health-checks) the following source range is hardcoded: `130.211.0.0/22`. Is this a fixed one or can I get it using some command (e.g. `gcloud`, `kubectl`)?

I have tried to inspect the K8s objects but I don't find a this source range in order to create the firewall rule pointed out in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That source IP range (`130.211.0.0/22`) is a fixed, global value that the GCE L7 load balancer will use when issuing health checks. You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#health_check_source_ips_and_firewall_rules).

Answer (score 2):

The source IPs for GCE L7 LB have now been updated to include `35.191.0.0/16`. The full list of source ranges is now `35.191.0.0/16, 130.211.0.0/22`. (See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/).)